# Proving $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x-3}}\right) = \frac35$

Tags: limits, fractions, radicals

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x-3}}\right)$$

Can someone help me to solve it?

result of online calculator: 3/5

Comment: Can u please re-write the function? Its not clear

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SE! Please ensure that your question is fully understandable without the title. The title's purpose is to attract people to your question (and to make it easily searchable). Once it has done that, it's job is done. The question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x-3}}\right) = \left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x-3}}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x-3}}\right)=\frac{\big(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-2}\big)\big(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x-3}\big)}{5}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x-3}} = \frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x-3}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x-3}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $$A=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x-3}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+1/x}-\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-2/x}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+2/x}-\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-3/x}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+1/x}-\sqrt{1-2/x}}{\sqrt{1+2/x}-\sqrt{1-3/x}}$$ Replace $\frac 1x$ by $y$; so $$A=\frac{\sqrt{1+y}-\sqrt{1-2y}}{\sqrt{1+2y}-\sqrt{1-3y}}$$ Now, use the fact  that, when $z$ is small compared to $1$,$\sqrt{1+z}\approx 1+\frac z2$. Replace $z$ by the appropriate value for each radical.

I am sure that you can take from here.